# File stored in a text field on SQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server, file, field, blob

I have a little program in Java that I use to import files stored in blob fields. Now I came thru a new situation for me: a system stores files into database (SQL Server), but using a text field, not a blob (image, in SQL Server notation).

I've tried to load those files in many ways, but none worked. I've tried to read as blob; as InputStream; as String and convert to byte array. Nothing!

Somebody has a clue? What should I do?

My code is:

```
StringBuffer sqlSQLServer = new StringBuffer();
sqlSQLServer.append(" select cdAnexo, dsNomeArquivo, dnArquivo, dtAnexo, cdProcesso, cdAndamento ");
sqlSQLServer.append(" from TAnexo ");

psSQLServer = connSQLServer.prepareStatement(sqlSQLServer.toString());
rsSQLServer = psSQLServer.executeQuery();

while (rsSQLServer.next()){
    try{
        String nomeArquivo = rsSQLServer.getString("cdAnexo")  + "-" + rsSQLServer.getString("dsNomeArquivo");
        nomeArquivo = nomeArquivo.replaceAll(" ", "_");
        File arquivo = new File(diretorio, nomeArquivo);

        String blob = rsSQLServer.getString("dnArquivo");
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(arquivo);
        byte[] buff = blob.getBytes();
        out.write(buff);
        out.close();

        System.out.println("Arquivo " + nomeArquivo + " gravado com sucesso.");
    } catch(Exception e){
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

No error is thrown. The file is generated, but it appears corrupted in case of .pdf files. When I load .doc files the file is generated with a characters sequence.

Comment: Start by posting your code on here

Comment: Whenever I've used tables to store BLOB strings, I've used VARCHAR(MAX).  

What is the exact error that is being thrown?

Comment: Code and answer about error thrown were added.